# Programmatically add contact in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, abaddressbook

I want to add a contact (just the name and phone number) programatically in Swift. I've found some Objective-C examples but I didn't get them to work, not even in Objective-C. I don't want this to involve AddressBookUI, because I want to get the values from my own UI.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a quick method to add a contact in Swift.  I verified it on my iPhone 5 iOS 7.1 as I've found the simulator doesn't always match the same results as my phone does for AB stuff.

You can add a button and point to this method:

```
@IBAction func createContact(sender: AnyObject) {
    var newContact:ABRecordRef! = ABPersonCreate().takeRetainedValue()
    var success:Bool = false
    var newFirstName:NSString = "AA"
    var newLastName = "a"

//Updated to work in Xcode 6.1
        var error: Unmanaged<CFErrorRef>? = nil
//Updated to error to &error so the code builds in Xcode 6.1
    success = ABRecordSetValue(newContact, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, newFirstName, &error)
    println("setting first name was successful? \(success)")
    success = ABRecordSetValue(newContact, kABPersonLastNameProperty, newLastName, &error)
    println("setting last name was successful? \(success)")
    success = ABAddressBookAddRecord(adbk, newContact, &error)
    println("Adbk addRecord successful? \(success)")
    success = ABAddressBookSave(adbk, &error)
    println("Adbk Save successful? \(success)")

}//createContact
```

btw-it assumes you've already got an addressbook var assigned, which you can on opening the view by overriding viewDidAppear.  It does the security prompt as well:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if !self.authDone {
        self.authDone = true
        let stat = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()
        switch stat {
        case .Denied, .Restricted:
            println("no access")
        case .Authorized, .NotDetermined:
            var err : Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil
            var adbk : ABAddressBook? = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &err).takeRetainedValue()
            if adbk == nil {
                println(err)
                return
            }
            ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(adbk) {
                (granted:Bool, err:CFError!) in
                if granted {
                    self.adbk = adbk
                } else {
                    println(err)
                }//if
            }//ABAddressBookReqeustAccessWithCompletion
        }//case
    }//if
}//viewDidAppear
```

Comment: Good answer. BTW, where you call `ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions`, though, your `err` is unmanaged, so unless you call `takeRetainedValue()` for the err, this will leak. Likewise, where you're setting the properties of the `ABRecordRef`, (a) I think you can eliminate that `UnsafeMutablePointer` and just use `var error: Unmanaged<CFErrorRef>?`; and (b) if any of these lines generate an error, you'll want to likewise want to `takeRetainedValue`.

Comment: Thanks - I spent an hour learning what Unmanaged was the other day so I finally understand what you wrote here :) https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_41

Comment: Figured out how to resolve the Xcode 6.1 error that Rob highlighted months ago.  Changing to his suggested syntax, and instead of passing in error as a param, passing in &error, a pointer.

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 4 & 5**

```
import ContactsUI
```

**Inherit this class CNContactViewControllerDelegate**

```
@IBOutlet var contactNameTxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var phoneNumberTxt: UITextField!

@IBAction func saveActionBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let store = CNContactStore()
        let contact = CNMutableContact()

        // Name
        contact.givenName = contactNameTxt.text ?? ""

        // Phone
        contact.phoneNumbers.append(CNLabeledValue(
            label: "mobile", value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: phoneNumberTxt.text ?? "")))

        // Save
        let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
        saveRequest.add(contact, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)
        try? store.execute(saveRequest)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**Add contact with a button click using swift 3**

> Add this row in project plist

Privacy - Contacts Usage Description

then

```
import AddressBook
import Contacts
```

> On button click, you add the following

```
let newContact = CNMutableContact()
newContact.givenName = "Your Name"
newContact.jobTitle = "CTO xyz Company"

let workEmail = CNLabeledValue(label:CNLabelWork, value:"demoxyz@gmail.com" as NSString)
newContact.emailAddresses = [workEmail]
newContact.phoneNumbers = [CNLabeledValue(
    label:CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone,
    value:CNPhoneNumber(stringValue:"0123456789"))]
do {
    let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
    saveRequest.add(newContact, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)
    try AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().contactStore.execute(saveRequest)
} catch {
    AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().showMessage("Unable to save the new contact.")
}
```

> On app delegate add some custom class

```
// MARK: Custom functions        
class func getAppDelegate() -> AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
}

func showMessage(_ message: String) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Birthdays", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    let dismissAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action) -> Void in
    }

    alertController.addAction(dismissAction)

    let pushedViewControllers = (self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).viewControllers
    let presentedViewController = pushedViewControllers[pushedViewControllers.count - 1]

    presentedViewController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func requestForAccess(_ completionHandler: @escaping (_ accessGranted: Bool) -> Void) {
    let authorizationStatus = CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: CNEntityType.contacts)

    switch authorizationStatus {
    case .authorized:
        completionHandler(true)

    case .denied, .notDetermined:
        self.contactStore.requestAccess(for: CNEntityType.contacts, completionHandler: { (access, accessError) -> Void in
            if access {
                completionHandler(access)
            }
            else {
                if authorizationStatus == CNAuthorizationStatus.denied {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                        let message = "\(accessError!.localizedDescription)\n\nPlease allow the app to access your contacts through the Settings."
                        self.showMessage(message)
                    })
                }
            }
        })

    default:
        completionHandler(false)
    }
}
```

You are done; test the project and check the contact app.

Comment: You have to add "let contactStore = CNContactStore()" in the button's view

Comment: It's not a question.. you simply forgot to add the line that I wrote in your code example.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I used the following lines of code

```
var addressBook : ABAddressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreate()
var contactPerson : ABRecordRef = ABPersonCreate()

ABRecordSetValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, txtFirstName.text, nil);
ABRecordSetValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty, txtLastName.text, nil);
```

But when the record that gets inserted contains "nil"

while reading contacts from address book the following snippet helped

```
var firstName: NSString! = Unmanaged<CFString>.fromOpaque(ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue().__conversion()
```

Comment: 1. `ABAddressBookCreate()` is deprecated. You really should use `ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions()`. For example, `let addressBook:ABAddressBookRef! = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &error).takeRetainedValue()`. 2. In the latest betas, the `fromOpaque`/`toOpaque` dance is no longer needed. For example, `let first = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as String`.